# How to run VBScript from command line

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I am a beginner in VBScript.

I need execute in VBScript this command line:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini MySQL
```

I googled it & got to know that we can run VBScript from command line by executing below command and I have tried this:

```
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")          
oShell.run "cmd /k ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini MySQL", 1, True
```

But the script is stopped because in the path of the file `my.ini` there are some folder with space in the name, that is `Program Files` and `MySQL Server 5.5`

How to do resolve this?

Comment: You need to double the quotes to escape them, try this `oShell.run "cmd /k ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini MySQL""", 1, True`.

Comment: You should probably look at the usage information presented when entering `cscript /?` at the Command Prompt too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the Filepath in a Variable and run it.

```
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim path = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini MySQL"         
oShell.run "cmd /k " path , 1, True
```

Good Luck

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

First : To make life easier just use this function to double quotes your strings and debug your command with `wscript.echo` or a `MsgBox` before executing it !

```
SQL_CMD = "cmd /k "& DblQuote("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe") &_
"--defaults-file="& DblQuote("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini") & " MySQL"
wscript.echo SQL_CMD
'--------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'--------------------------------------
```